# Jenkins reporting from XML file

Tags: python, xml, jenkins

this is my first post so sorry if there exists answer for a problem I 've got, but I think it is very specific.

My teammates created a very simple testing environment which tests functions in cpp project and it produces report of launched testcases to txt file which looks like this:
0 testcase1 PASS
1 testcase2 PASS
2 testcase2 FAIL
and so on

My task is to prepare an xml file from this txt and put it to Jenkins to generate pretty charts with test run.

Currently I try to parse this txt to JUnitXml file generated by Python lxml library.

Xml file from this txt looks like this:
[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69wTP.png)

When I put it to Jenkins it produces me only result of tests which were run, in this case all tests were launched.
What am I missing in my XML file?
Do I need any external library to our test environment which would produce better xml with information about passed, failed testcases?

Cheers.

Comment: Sounds like your teammates just initiated their own unit testing framework. Why not use an existing, mature unit testing framework rather than re-inventing the wheel? My teammates had great experience integrating GoogleTest framework into an existing C++ project. Integrating it into Jenkins was easy as well with the xUnit plugin.

Comment: Of course, before I came to this project they tried to use existing testing framework, it was probably Boost Test Library, which turned their existing code to it's own or smth like that so they left it, there was also a topic with GoogleTest but a person who was responsible to get some information about it was moved to another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should find in your xml report according to your report :

```
<testsuite skip="0" failures="1" errors="0" tests="3" name="Name of the tests">
    <testcase name="testcase1" classname="This is a name to identify in which class is located the test"/>
    <testcase name="testcase2" classname="This is another(or not) name to identify in which class is located the test"/>
    <testcase name="testcase3" classname="This is another(or not) name to identify in which class is located the test">
        <failure message="Any message of the failing output" type="You can specify the kind of error">
            <![CDATA[ "Here you can put a complete stacktrace or 
any log message associated with your failure" ]]> 
        </failure>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

You can find the description (Schema) of the [JUnit XML format here](https://github.com/windyroad/JUnit-Schema)